# Checking if a div has child element - Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to check if a `div` has a child element and then add  CSS (`display: none`).

But my code is working neither with single or double equal character.

```
<div class="flex-video mb-30 "> 

</div>
```

And my codes are :

```
if ($(".flex-video").children().length == 0) {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: What is `$(this)` here.. Could you please elaborate what's not working? and FYI, it never works with `=` in `if` condition.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you simply do:

```
$(".flex-video :not(:has(*) )").hide();
```

or:

```
$(".flex-video :empty").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` doesn't refer to `.flex-video` in your code. I would assign that element to a variable, then just reference the variable in the rest of your code.

```js
var $flexVideo = $(".flex-video");
if ($flexVideo.children().length == 0){
    $flexVideo.css('display', 'none');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-video mb-30 "> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working as expected because `this` doesn't refer to the element that you are trying to target. By default, `this` refers to the `window` object, and without seeing your full code, that is probably what is happening.

You could either re-specify the jQuery selector:

```
if ($(".flex-video").children().length === 0) {
    $(".flex-video").css('display', 'none');
}
```

...or store the jQuery selector in a variable:

```
var $flexVideo = $(".flex-video")
if ($flexVideo.children().length === 0) {
    $flexVideo.css('display', 'none');
}
```

However, it's worth pointing out that the two snippets above wouldn't work if there are multiple `.flex-video` elements because you are only checking the first one. It would be better to iterate over all of the `.flex-video` elements in case there is more than one.

In the snippet below, `this` is bound to the current `.flex-video` element that is being iterated over because the `.each()` method provides context for the `this` value:

```
$(".flex-video").each(function () {
  if ($(this).children().length === 0) {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could also make the conditional check within the context of the `.css()` method because `this` will be bound to the `.flex-video` element. Internally, jQuery will iterate over all of the elements similar to the `.each()` method example above.

```
$(".flex-video").css('display', function() {
  return $(this).children().length === 0 ? 'none': '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.each($('.flex-video'), function(idx, ele) {
    if ($(ele).children().length == 0) {
        $(ele).css({"display": "none"});
    }
});
```

This iterates through each element with class .flex-video and assigns to ele, if ele doesn't have children, it sets display property to none.